# CUDA: Maximum number of blocks in a grid != CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAX_GRID_DIM_X?

Tags: cuda

I want to start a kernel in such a fashion:

```
kernel_code<<<NUMBER_BLOCKS, NUMBER_THREADS_PER_BLOCK>>> (param1, param2, param3, param4);
```

Thus, using only the x-dimension of the grid. I want to call the kernel with the maximum number of blocks possible. I thought the max. number of blocks in a grid for one dimension would be 65535.

However, I explored the constant `CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAX_GRID_DIM_X` which sounds like exact the same number I want to find out. However, this constant returns 1899336 on my GeForce 210 (CUDA 1.2). What am I getting wrong?

Comment: So your doubt is what is CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAX_GRID_DIM_X ? or something else ?

Comment: I am looking for the max. number of blocks I can assign to the kernel, when I call it in the way shown above (only one dimension used).

According to the API CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAX_BLOCK_DIM_X is the 'maximum x-dimension of a block', which seems to refer to the maximum number of threads I can assign to one block's dimension. Thus, this might not be the number I am looking for.

Comment: So it is correct that CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAX_BLOCK_DIM_X is the wrong constant. But what value is the correct value then?

Answer (score 2):

Referring to the driver API documentation for [cuDeviceGetAttribute](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__DEVICE.html#group__CUDA__DEVICE_1g9c3e1414f0ad901d3278a4d6645fc266),  the parameter which gives the maximum number of blocks in the x-direction of a grid is:

> •CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAX_GRID_DIM_X: Maximum x-dimension of a grid;

As you surmised, the parameter you indicated gives the maximum number of threads in a block (x-dimension):

> •CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAX_BLOCK_DIM_X: Maximum x-dimension of a block;

On a [GeForce 210](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus), the `MAX_GRID_DIM_X` parameter should be 65535. ([True for all cc 1.x devices.](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#features-and-technical-specifications))

If you are getting some other number, there is either something wrong with your code that you are using to retrieve this data (which you haven't shown), or else something wrong with your machine setup.

Try running and also inspecting the code for the CUDA driver API [deviceQuery sample](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#device-query-driver-api).